# Error on data binding kotlin android studio 3.6.3

Tags: android, api, android-studio, kotlin, android-mvvm

okay, I create apps use data binding by following this tutorial on youtube I followed the tutorial until part four, but in the last minute of this fourth tutorial I run into a lot of problems when I run the application that I sample from this video tutorial.

this is the youtube link : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EUgpvEno3vI&list=PLk7v1Z2rk4hjtIT9TCKIcl2YJYfDlZ_4v&index=4

this is my recyclerview_movie :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>
        <import type="android.view.View" />
        <variable
            name="movie"
            type="com.example.recyclerviewmvvm.Movie" />
    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_margin="3dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="195dp">

                    <ImageView
                        app:image="@{movie.image}"
                        android:id="@+id/imageView"
                        android:background="@drawable/captain_marvel"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:scaleType="matrix"
                        android:layout_height="195dp"
                        />

                    <TextView
                        android:visibility="@{movie.is_new == 0 ? View.INVISIBLE : View.VISIBLE}"
                        android:background="#1C9603"
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                        android:padding="2dp"
                        android:width="38dp"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:id="@+id/textViewIsNew"
                        android:text="New"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textViewRating"
                        android:text="UA"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                        android:padding="4dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:background="@drawable/textview_round_border_background"
                        android:textSize="10sp"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:layout_width="25dp"
                        android:layout_height="25dp"/>

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/layout_like"
                        android:paddingTop="3dp"
                        android:paddingBottom="3dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="12dp"
                        android:paddingRight="12dp"
                        android:layout_margin="15dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:background="@drawable/relativelayout_background"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                            android:id="@+id/imageViewLike"
                            android:background="@drawable/ic_like"
                            android:layout_width="15dp"
                            android:layout_height="14dp"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageViewLike"
                            android:textSize="17sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:textColor="#ffffff"
                            android:id="@+id/textViewLikePercent"
                            android:text="78%"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:text="23023 votes"
                            android:textSize="10sp"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                            android:layout_below="@id/textViewLikePercent"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                            android:id="@+id/textViewVotesCount"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


                    </RelativeLayout>

                </RelativeLayout>


                <RelativeLayout
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textViewTitle"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textColor="#1A1A1A"
                        android:text="@{movie.title}"
                        tools:text="Captain Marvel"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:text="@{movie.language}"
                        tools:text="English"
                        android:id="@+id/textViewLanguage"
                        android:layout_below="@id/textViewTitle"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/button_book"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:text="Book"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

                </RelativeLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:background="#414141"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewType"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:text="@{movie.type}"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
                    android:padding="2dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/textview_border_background"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_width="28dp"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

this is first error :

```
location: package com.example.recyclerviewmvvm.databinding
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptExecution
   > java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)

* Try:
Run with --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$3.accept(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:166)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$3.accept(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:163)
    at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:191)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:156)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:108)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveBeforeExecutionOutputsTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveBeforeExecutionOutputsTaskExecuter.java:67)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.StartSnapshotTaskInputsBuildOperationTaskExecuter.execute(StartSnapshotTaskInputsBuildOperationTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveAfterPreviousExecutionStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveAfterPreviousExecutionStateTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:94)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:95)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:43)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:355)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:343)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:336)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:322)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:134)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:202)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:193)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
Caused by: org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkExecutionException: A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptExecution
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkItemExecution.waitForCompletion(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:375)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.waitForItemsAndGatherFailures(DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.java:142)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.access$000(DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.java:34)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultAsyncWorkTracker$1.run(DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.java:106)
    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withoutLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:260)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withoutProjectLock(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:171)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withoutProjectLock(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.withoutProjectLock(StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.java:95)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.waitForItemsAndGatherFailures(DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.java:102)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.waitForAll(DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.java:80)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.waitForCompletion(DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.java:68)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$5.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:484)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:402)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:394)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:92)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:461)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:444)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.access$200(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:93)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:237)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.lambda$execute$0(ExecuteStep.java:32)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:32)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupOutputsStep.execute(CleanupOutputsStep.java:58)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupOutputsStep.execute(CleanupOutputsStep.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:48)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:39)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:73)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CatchExceptionStep.execute(CatchExceptionStep.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:51)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SnapshotOutputsStep.execute(SnapshotOutputsStep.java:45)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SnapshotOutputsStep.execute(SnapshotOutputsStep.java:31)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.executeWithoutCache(CacheStep.java:208)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:70)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:45)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.execute(BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.java:49)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreSnapshotsStep.execute(StoreSnapshotsStep.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreSnapshotsStep.execute(StoreSnapshotsStep.java:32)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.executeBecause(SkipUpToDateStep.java:96)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.lambda$execute$0(SkipUpToDateStep.java:89)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:76)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:37)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:48)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:69)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:47)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultWorkExecutor.execute(DefaultWorkExecutor.java:33)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:140)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptExecution.run(KaptWithoutKotlincTask.kt:158)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.AdapterWorkAction.execute(AdapterWorkAction.java:50)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerServer.execute(DefaultWorkerServer.java:47)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:65)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:61)
    at org.gradle.internal.classloader.ClassLoaderUtils.executeInClassloader(ClassLoaderUtils.java:98)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.execute(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:61)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:44)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:41)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker.executeWrappedInBuildOperation(AbstractWorker.java:41)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.execute(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:56)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$3.call(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:215)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$3.call(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:210)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runExecution(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:215)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runBatch(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:164)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.run(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:131)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.util.KaptBaseError: Exception while annotation processing
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing(annotationProcessing.kt:84)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing$default(annotationProcessing.kt:35)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.Kapt.kapt(Kapt.kt:45)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: android.databinding.tool.util.LoggedErrorException: Found data binding error(s):

[databinding] {"msg":"Cannot find a setter for \u003candroid.widget.ImageView app:image\u003e that accepts parameter type \u0027java.lang.String\u0027\n\nIf a binding adapter provides the setter, check that the adapter is annotated correctly and that the parameter type matches.","file":"/Users/misbahbagaskarapurwanto/Desktop/RecyclerviewMVVM/app/src/main/res/layout/recyclerview_movie.xml","pos":[{"line0":31,"col0":37,"line1":31,"col1":47}]}

    at android.databinding.tool.processing.Scope.assertNoError(Scope.java:111)
    at android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessDataBinding.doProcess(ProcessDataBinding.java:123)
    at android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessDataBinding.process(ProcessDataBinding.java:87)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.incremental.IncrementalProcessor.process(incrementalProcessors.kt)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.ProcessorWrapper.process(annotationProcessing.kt:147)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.callProcessor(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:794)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.access$200(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:91)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$DiscoveredProcessors$ProcessorStateIterator.runContributingProcs(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:627)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.run(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1033)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.doProcessing(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1198)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1170)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1068)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing(annotationProcessing.kt:79)
    ... 28 more


* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 4s
```

this is my second error :

```
  /Users/misbahbagaskarapurwanto/Desktop/RecyclerviewMVVM/app/build/generated/source/kapt/debug/com/example/recyclerviewmvvm/DataBinderMapperImpl.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
    import com.example.recyclerviewmvvm.databinding.RecyclerviewMovieBindingImpl;
                                                   ^
      symbol:   class RecyclerviewMovieBindingImpl
```

this is my third error :

```
  Caused by: org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkExecutionException: A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptExecution
```

this is my fourth error :

```
  Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

this is my fifth error :

```
  Caused by: org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.util.KaptBaseError: Exception while annotation processing
```

this is my sixth error :

```
Cannot find a setter for <android.widget.ImageView app:image> that accepts parameter type 'java.lang.String'

If a binding adapter provides the setter, check that the adapter is annotated correctly and that the parameter type matches
```

about the class you can find at my github : `https://github.com/misbagas/RecyclerviewMVVM`

Comment: for the first one, you don't have binding adapter app:image="@{movie.image}" i guess.

Comment: but in the tutorial, I must add app:image="@{movie.image}"